# Changing font size of all labels in annotated attribute table in ArcGIS Pro to be one size

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, labeling, attribute-table, annotation

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I converted a large group of labels to annotation (every road of a city) but when annotated, the size of the labels are a little too large for the map size I want. I can change the size of each individual label within the attribute table, but I can't figure out a way to change the size of all the fonts at once since I want them to be an identical size. Without figuring this out, I'll be stuck changing the font size for thousands of individual labels.

Comment: select all the rows you want to update  in the attribute table and then do a field calculate on the font size field.

Comment: Thank you! Simple solution I was completely overthinking.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to access the Symbology of the Annotation layer.  Under "Symbol Substitution" > double-click the grey box in "Substitute symbols in collection" > then either select a font symbology from Gallery OR go into the Properties tab, and change the font accordingly and then hit "Apply".
If you want to go back to your original Annotation font, choose "No substitutions" in Symbology.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the annotation you want to change. A list of all those objects will be shown on the right side under Modify Features. Once you have selected all the objects you want to change, click on attributes and the text dialog box should open. In the Modify Features box, you will see that the first feature will be highlighted. Select the layer name shown above that first feature at the top and then change your text to whatever font or size you require and click on Apply.